# Create a tuple using loop with possibly None element

Tags: python, tuples

please see the code below.

I need to create a tuple, where many elements are empty(`None`). So, I am creating a `list` and then converting it to a `tuple`.
I know tuple is immutable, and hence, is there a standard way of creating a tuple? (I am worried). How I can do better?

```
datadict = []
datadict.append(1)
datadict.append(name)
datadict.append(self.KeyEntry.get_text())
for field in self.fields:
    if self.all_fields[field].get_text():
        datadict.append(self.all_fields[field].get_text())
    else:
        datadict.append(None)
datatup = tuple(datadict)
```

Answer (score 1):

what about this?

```
data = tuple(self.all_fields[field].get_text() or None for field in self.fields)
```